# Reading input values in ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

whenever trying to input values from keyboard using ipython notebook using the input() function like python, it gives error.

```
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-725a22d6f154> in <module>()
     8 #Reads three Input values for x,y and z
     9 print "Enter Values of x, y, z :- "
---> 10 x = input()
     11 y = input()
     12 z = input()

EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

the same works correctly in python.  how can I do this in ipython notebook environment?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use `raw_input`. (and some more chars so the SO allow me to post the answer)

Comment: @reshmig whats the error? I've used `raw_input` as well and it works great.

Comment: it is not asking for the input values and shows the error EOFError

Comment: while using raw_input() function, it shows the error that this frontend does not support stdin.

Comment: only 1.0 support it in the notebook.